# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2n+k+1}{n}/2^{2n+k+1}=1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to find a closed form for the sum
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2n+k+1}{n}/2^{2n+k+1}$.

According to Wolfram 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(2n%2Bk%2B1)!%2F(n!*n%2Bk%2B1)!*2%5E(2n%2Bk%2B1))+from+k%3D0+to+infinity
this sum evaluates to 1, but I can't figure out how to prove this.
Any hints.

Comment: This maybe a far fetch but if you set a=2 in the formula under the subtitle "5. An asymptotic formula for the inversion numbers" in the following link, it may lead you to some clue: https://academic.csuohio.edu/bmargolius/homepage/inversions/invers.htm

Comment: @ZaeemHussain $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2\,n+k+1}{n}}{2^{2\,n+k+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\Gamma(n+2)}{2^{2\,n+1}\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} (2\,n+3)\right)}\binom{2\,n+1}{n} =1$ perhaps provides some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preliminary**
$$
\begin{align}
a_n
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{k+n}{k}}{2^k}\tag{1a}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{k+n-1}{k-1}+\binom{k+n-1}{k}}{2^k}\tag{1b}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\binom{k+n}{k}}{2^{k+1}}+\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{k+n-1}{k}}{2^k}\tag{1c}\\
&=\frac12a_n-\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{n+1}}+a_{n-1}+\frac{\binom{2n-1}{n}}{2^n}\tag{1d}\\[3pt]
&=\frac12a_n+a_{n-1}\tag{1e}\\[9pt]
&=2a_{n-1}\tag{1f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: define $a_n$
$\text{(1b)}$: Pascal Identity
$\text{(1c)}$: substitute $k\mapsto k+1$ in the left sum
$\text{(1d)}$: apply $\text{(1a)}$
$\text{(1e)}$: cancel terms
$\text{(1f)}$: $2$ times $\text{(1e)}$ minus $\text{(1a)}$

Since $a_0=1$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{k+n}{k}}{2^k}=2^n\tag2
$$

---

**Answer**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2n+k+1}{n}}{2^{2n+k+1}}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2n+k+1}{n+k+1}}{2^{2n+k+1}}\tag{3a}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+k+1}\frac{\binom{-n-1}{n+k+1}}{2^{n+k+1}}\tag{3b}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\binom{-n-1}{k}}{2^k}\tag{3c}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}2^{n+1}-\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{\binom{-n-1}{k}}{2^k}\tag{3d}\\
&=2-\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{k+n}{k}}{2^k}\tag{3e}\\[9pt]
&=1\tag{3f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: symmetry of Pascal's Triangle
$\text{(3b)}$: negative binomial coefficient
$\text{(3c)}$: substitute $k\mapsto k-n-1$
$\text{(3d)}$: Binomial Theorem
$\text{(3e)}$: negative binomial coefficient
$\text{(3f)}$: apply $(2)$

Answer (score 4):

Recall that
$$
\binom nm=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=\rho}\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{m+1}}dz.\tag1
$$
Therefore, assuming $\rho<1$:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2n+k+1}{n}\left(\frac12\right)^{2n+k+1}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac12\right)^{2n+k+1}\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=\rho}\frac{(1+z)^{2n+k+1}}{z^{n+1}}dz\tag2\\
&=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=\rho}\left(\frac{1+z}2\right)^{2n+1}\frac{dz}{z^{n+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1+z}2\right)^{k}\tag3\\
&=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=\rho}\left(\frac{1+z}2\right)^{2n+1}
\frac1{1-\frac{1+z}2}\frac{dz}{z^{n+1}}\tag4\\
&=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=\rho}\left(\frac{1+z}2\right)^{2n+1}
\frac2{1-z}\frac{dz}{z^{n+1}}\tag5\\
&=\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac12\right)^{2n}\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\sum_{l=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}l z^l\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k\tag6\\
&=\left(\frac12\right)^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{n-k}\tag7\\
&=\left(\frac12\right)^{2n}2^{2n}=1.\tag8
\end{align}
$$

> Explanations:
>
> $(1)$ Follows from the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), since $\binom nm$
>     is the coefficient at $z^{-1} $ in the Laurent expansion of the integrand about $z=0$.
>
> $(2)$ The binomial coefficient is replaced according to $(1)$.
>
> $(3) $ The terms are rearranged and the order of integration and summation is interchanged (which is possible due to $\rho <1$).
>
> $(4) $ The geometric series is evaluated (which converges due to $\rho <1$).
>
> $(5) $ The result for the geometric series is rearranged.
>
> $(6) $ The residue theorem is applied. The terms $(1+z)^{2n+1}$ and $\dfrac1 {1-z}$ are expanded to binomial sum and geometric series, respectively.
>
> $(7) $ The residue, i.e. the coefficient at $z^{-1} $, is evaluated.
>
> $(8) $ The sum of the binomial coefficients is evaluated to $2^{2n}$ (since $2n+1$ is odd and exactly half of binomial coefficients is summed) which gives rise to the final result.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also point me to a reference for the formula relating the binomial coefficient to contour integration that you have in the beginning of the answer? Since I am not familiar with it I also couldn't follow the step where you get rid of the integral.

Comment: @ZaeemHussain I have added some explanations. Please let me know if it helps.